# Super expression must be either null or a function react-native and Realm DB

Tags: javascript, android, database, react-native, realm

I have a bit of sample code, however I am unable to get it to work, I get the error message "Super expression must be either null of a function, not undefined"

const Realm = require('realm');

```
class db extends Realm.Component {
    render() {
        let realm = new Realm({
            schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string'}}]
        });

        realm.write(() => {
        realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex'});
        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
    });
       return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
               <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                   Count of Dogs in Realm: {realm.objects('Dog').length}
               </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I should also note that I am testing in android.

This is the code I am running, any help would be appreciated, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your superclass is defined as `Realm.Component` where you probably meant `React.Component`. Also, after fixing that, please make sure you're using the latest version of Realm for React Native.